# How to install mariadb into my homestead+laravel?

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, vagrant, homestead

I was trying to install mariadb in my homestead, but it was failed, now shows me an error message, I don't like that message and I want that my homestead can run as before without any error message as that will show you

i ran sudo dpkg --configure -a but i can't solved it.

[image: Click here to view the error messages]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zl6z7.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read ["How to Ask"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), including the links at the bottom of the page, and ["Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We expect evidence of your effort, which should be where you've searched and why that didn't help, or your code written to solve the problem and an explanation of what that code doesn't work. Without that it looks like you're asking us to write the code for you, which is isn't what SO is for.

Comment: i typed a lot of command i can't get the answer.....

Answer (score 0):

Save your files, destroy the box and start fresh.

First you have to remove mysql server

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

then install mariadb

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 0xcbcb082a1bb943db
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb [arch=amd64,i386] http://sfo1.mirrors.digitalocean.com/mariadb/repo/10.1/ubuntu trusty main'

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mariadb-server
```

In your homestead.yaml file, use

mariadb:
    - homestead

Comment: this help me but i have another question!!! please i need to connect my database with navicat

Comment: Mark the answer as correct if it helped you. I sugest you using HeidiSql, it's a free, easy to use alternative. Just connect to localhost with user homestead,  password secret at port 33060.

Comment: the problem is i can't access to my user homestead because i have typed mysql -u homestead -p and asked for the password so i put 'secret' and display this  Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES), but when i put mysql -u root -p i can access with my password secret... What's my problem i need connect my database with navicat because i can ran my mgration but i wanna connect navicat with it.

Comment: okay now i did some changes for example: i can connect with mysql -u root -p the password is secret but i cannot connect my database with navicat i look everything by console, i would connect with my navicat... I ran my from my project with this config: hostname:localhost, database:homestead, user: root, password: secret. In my navicat i put the same but display 2003 - can-t connect to mysql server on 'localhost' (100061 "unknown error")

Comment: honestly this doens't work because altered my vagrant 
this sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 0xcbcb082a1bb943db
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb [arch=amd64,i386] http://sfo1.mirrors.digitalocean.com/mariadb/repo/10.1/ubuntu trusty main'

Comment: the best way is this sudo apt-get install mariadb-server

Comment: because this doens't help sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 0xcbcb082a1bb943db
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb [arch=amd64,i386] http://sfo1.mirrors.digitalocean.com/mariadb/repo/10.1/ubuntu trusty main'

Answer (score 0):

You can try removing the PPAs you added to try to install MariaDB.  They seem to be where the errors are coming from.

`sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:whatever/path/to/ppa`

It looks like there are 2 PPAs at issue based on your screenshot.

I would also uninstall any MariaDB components you tried installing before you remove the PPAs